# Is there CDN for polymer elements?

Tags: polymer, web-component

I would like to know if there are any CDNs for polymer elements, since you have to always download the elements and It would be more convinient to import it via cdn. Can't find any on google? Also are there any reasons that it does not exists or just because it is so new?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know any CDN hosting polymer elements right now and I assume it would be better to `vulcanize` them for a production environment but due to the fact that most of the elements are hosted on github you could link your imports to `rawgit.com`

**Example:**

```
<link rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Polymer/core-ajax/master/core-ajax.html">
```

Comment: This doesn't work --- most of the HTML files refer to files in other components via relative URLs, such as `../polymer/polymer.html`. Because the github directory layout has that extra `master` between the component name and the filename, none of these will resolve.

Comment: please don't do this, github isn't a cdn.

Comment: @PauloCheque https://rawgit.com/ is CDN and it is sending correct Content-Type header

Comment: @Nemo64 You might want to check out [RawGit.com](http://rawgit.com/), it definitely *is* a CDN.

Comment: @DavidGiven Yes you are right, transitive dependencies won't work. They require all elements to be inside the same folder. I set up a Git repo specifically for this purpose: [download/polymer-cdn](https://github.com/download/polymer-cdn). Also see my answer below.

Answer (score 22):

### There is now!

I created this GitHub repository specifically for this purpose:

### [download/polymer-cdn](https://github.com/download/polymer-cdn)

All GitHub repositories are automatically in CDN through [RawGit](http://rawgit.com/). So, using that, we can now import Polymer elements using markup like this (for `iron-icons` in this case):

```
<link rel="import" 
      href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.0.1/lib/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
```

The project structure was set up in such a way that imports from elements that you import (transitive dependencies) resolve correctly.

The readme for the repository has a list of all elements it contains.

Missing something? [Let me know](https://github.com/Download/polymer-cdn/issues) and I'll be happy to include it.

### Try it

You can try it out right now by hacking on this Codepen:

#### [Polymer-CDN Example](http://codepen.io/StijnDeWitt/pen/EyPyyL).

Or you can run this code snippet:

```html
<base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.5.0/lib/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html">
<style is="custom-style">
  :root {
    --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: var(--paper-light-blue-900);
    --paper-tab-ink: var(--paper-light-blue-100);
    --paper-tabs: {
      color: white;
      background-color: var(--paper-light-blue-500);
    };
  }
</style>

<div>
  <paper-button raised><iron-icon icon="check"></iron-icon>OK</paper-button>
  <paper-button raised><iron-icon icon="clear"></iron-icon>Cancel</paper-button>
</div>

<p><paper-checkbox>Checkbox</paper-checkbox></p>

<p><paper-toggle-button></paper-toggle-button></p>

<paper-tabs selected="0">
  <paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

Comment: cool initiative but I need recent element (submenu) not available in your cdn

Comment: @maxiplay Working on it. In the future please use the GitHub issue tracker as I check that more often.

Comment: @maxiplay I have updated it to version 1.1.3 of Polymer. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @maxiplay Any feedback?

Comment: Yes it's work perfectly. Thank you. I will can post my plunker to polymer team for bug with my attempt to build recursive paper-menu http://plnkr.co/edit/KqR3X5PKfuTKq7oNgTvO?p=info

Comment: @maxiplay Great! Thanks for the feedback. And don't forget to upvote if it helped you :)

Comment: could you provide an example using iron-selector component?

Answer (score 7):

You can also access polymer elements directly from `polymer-project.org`.

**Example**:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
```

Comment: And unfortunately without https you can't use that as a source for Google Apps Script!

Comment: This is for `0.5`, which is deprecated. I think something similar exists for `1.0`... But in both cases you are linking to some 'master' version which is not wise imho. You should link to a specific version that won't suddenly change on you.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but there is a non-hacky solution now: http://polygit.org/

It uses rawgit behind the curtains but provides a much nicer api.

Comment: Polygit is deprecated now

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at cloudflares polymer CDN:
http://cdnjs.com/libraries/polymer

Comment: How i can use polymer.js if i need paper and core elements?

Answer (score 1):

**rawgit option**

You would have to manage some dependencies manually since core-ajax.html returns 404 on polymer.html. Also rawgit.com cache is set to only 5 min (cache-control:max-age=300). 5 min cache is fine for version control, but it should be more for CDN (https://rawgit.com/Polymer/core-ajax/0.4.1/core-xhr.html). Also files are not minified.

**vulcanize option**

Probably best option before http/2 release. You would have to spend some time with configuration and integration into your build process. Also you don't have any CDN benefits (no data cost, already cached resources from third party domains.)

**conclusion**

There will be some CDN with minified polymer versions and long expires header on http/2 release. But I don't know about any right now.

Comment: Note that if you tag the version you want to use (a good habit anyway), rawgit allows you to use URLs that will never expire from cache. Actually the other way (directly from master) is only allowed for testing purposes. They will throttle and eventually block you if you send too much traffic there.