# Polymer.ImportStatus is undefined error

Tags: polymer, polymer-designer-tool

I am unable to run the polymer using the bower components but it is able to run through online path which is

```
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html"> 
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
```

When I'm using these files from bower components it is showing many errors...

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html"> 
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
```

Here the answer is helpful.

[Is there CDN for polymer elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843397/is-there-cdn-for-polymer-elements)

put the s in http

The rank is low.I could not write a comment
Please understand