# Importing Polymer html pages in Phoenix Framework

Tags: polymer, phoenix-framework, brunch

I am attempting to include my Polymer tools in my template page but the server is not properly routing to the files. I have put the files in their respective paths, but I get a 404 when I click on the live links.

```
    <link rel="import" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/assets/polymer/iron-elements/iron-pages/iron-pages.html") %>"/>
<link rel="import" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/assets/polymer/iron-elements/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html") %>"/>
<link rel="import" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/assets/polymer/iron-elements/iron-meta/iron-meta.html") %>"/>
<link rel="import" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/assets/polymer/iron-elements/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.html") %>"/>
<link rel="import" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/assets/polymer/iron-elements/iron-iconset/iron-iconset.html") %>"/>
<link rel="import" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/assets/polymer/iron-elements/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html") %>"/>
<link rel="import" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/assets/polymer/iron-elements/iron-icons/iron-icons.html") %>"/>
<link rel="import" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/assets/polymer/iron-elements/iron-icons/maps-icons.html") %>"/>
<link rel="import" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/assets/polymer/iron-elements/iron-icons/social-icons.html") %>"/>
```

Comment: Make sure brunch is running and make sure the polymer assets are output to "priv/static". In particular, your assets should be under "/web/static/assets/polymer" if you want them to be copied as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [vulcanize](https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize) to build a single file from multiple dependencies. Here is example setup for following elements:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Your favourite pastry">
  <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item>Croissant</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Donut</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Financier</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Madeleine</paper-item>
  </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Create `target.html`:

```
<link rel=import href=bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html>
<link rel=import href=bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html>
<link rel=import href=bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html>
```

Vulcanize elements:

```
vulcanize --inline-scripts --inline-css target.html > web/static/assets/polymer/rubber.html
```

Start serving `polymer` assets by adding into `endpoint.ex`:

```
only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt polymer)
```

Add HTML import for the bundle:

```
<link rel="import" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/polymer/rubber.html") %>">
```

Most probably you would like to serve polyfill library also. Copy `webcomponents-lite.js` under `web/static/vendor/` for this.

NOTE: brunch produces following error:

> Component JSON file "bower_components/paper-elements/.bower.json" must have `main` property.

and stop processing other `bower_components` AFAICS. To prevent it you may work with bower/vulcanize from within some sub-folder of you project root. Moreover there is no need to process polymer's `bower_components` with brunch while you are using vulcanize.

See also a [question about Polymer CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843397/is-there-cdn-for-polymer-elements) - it may be possibly to load elements from CDN.

Comment: Isn't the bower.json file unnecessary? Couldn't it just be deleted would that solve the error you describe with with brunch. I do like the second approach you mention with vulcanize. Thank you.

But this does not solve what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: You know what I went with this solution. I still feel like there should be a better solution, but thank you.

Comment: There are following improvements I can see:

- vulcanize plugin would be added for brunch (currently [available for grunt and others](https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize#what-about-build-tools));
- http 2 would allow individual elements push;

Polymer probably would switch from bower to [npm3](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/326#issuecomment-113594766). Not sure if this would improve anything, but IMHO worth to check on arrival.

I am using following Makefile meanwhile https://gist.github.com/webengineer-max/485af4435ed4fdbafc97.

Comment: I got my files all vulcanized now how are they served up? I tried creating a controller, but page inherited my layout template.

Comment: Vulcanize output is a static asset, no controller needed - http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/static-assets#section-default-configuration-and-workflow.

Comment: One last thing my vulcanized code keeps coming out with some duplicate code. The code usually includes registerElement('dom-module')

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have your static asset path incorrect. I believe if you change it to:

```
"/polymer/iron-elements/..."
```

(notice the removal of "/assets"). You should be good to go.

Comment: I am still getting there error even after removing assets from the path. I have even tried "polymer/..." I have my HTML pages under "/web/assets/polymer/..." So I would expect my original path to work :-/